# Drupal 7: Display last updated date for node

Tags: php, drupal

I created a content type that includes a Posted Date field with a machine name "field_publish_date"

what i have currently is the field displayed as "Posted on: 27 May 2014"

What i want to do is to display this field as the following format:

Posted on: 27 May 2014  |  Updated on: 30 May 2014

Could you please help with that.

Comment: Drupal node objects have an attribute to save the creation date, and an attribute to store the timestamp when the node wast last changed, so you do not need to add an extra field. See https://www.drupal.org/node/49768

Comment: I added this field because i want to publish a node with a specific date (not auto generated) this is why i used to create a field called Post date.

I want to check if the modified date is different than the post date, then display it as the format "Posted on: 27 May 2014 | Updated on: 30 May 2014"